# Cannot get ngMessages to validate

Tags: angularjs

I have installed angular-messages via npm and passed ngMessages to my application.
I added the directive to my partial html, but the %error blank

template:

```
<div ng-controller='friendsController'>
    <form>
        <table id='friendForm'>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='text' name='fname' ng-model='newFriend.fname' required/></td>
                <td>First Name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='text' name='lname' ng-model='newFriend.lname' required/></td>
                <td>Last Name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='date' name='bday' ng-model='newFriend.bday' required/></td>
                <td>Birthday</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='submit' value='Create' ng-click='addFriend()'/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <pre>friendForm.fname.$error = {{ friendForm.fname.$error.required | json }}</pre>

        <div ng-messages='friendForm.fname.$error' style='color:red' role='alert'>
            <p ng-message='required'>First Name is Required</p>
        </div>
        <div ng-messages='friendForm.lname.$error'>
            <p ng-message='required'>Last Name is Required</p>
        </div>
        <div ng-messages='friendForm.bday.$error'>
            <p ng-message='required'>Birthdate is Required</p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your `<form>` a `name` attribute of `friendForm` because you are trying to reference the form i.e. `friendForm.fname.$error`.

Taken from the [forms documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state):

> A form is an instance of FormController. The form instance can
>   optionally be published into the scope using the name attribute.
>
> Similarly, an input control that has the ngModel directive holds an
>   instance of NgModelController. Such a control instance can be
>   published as a property of the form instance using the name attribute
>   on the input control. The name attribute specifies the name of the
>   property on the form instance.
>
> This implies that the internal state of both the form and the control
>   is available for binding in the view using the standard binding
>   primitives.

Here is your code working with the name attribute.

```js
// app.js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', ['ngMessages']);

})();

// main.controller.js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app').controller('friendsController', friendsController);

  friendsController.$inject = [];

  function friendsController() {

  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='friendsController'>
  <form name="friendForm">
    <table id='friendForm'>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='text' name='fname' ng-model='newFriend.fname' required/></td>
        <td>First Name</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='text' name='lname' ng-model='newFriend.lname' required/></td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='date' name='bday' ng-model='newFriend.bday' required/></td>
        <td>Birthday</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='submit' value='Create' ng-click='addFriend()' /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <pre>friendForm.fname.$error = {{ friendForm.fname.$error.required | json }}</pre>

    <div ng-messages='friendForm.fname.$error' style='color:red' role='alert'>
      <p ng-message='required'>First Name is Required</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-messages='friendForm.lname.$error'>
      <p ng-message='required'>Last Name is Required</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-messages='friendForm.bday.$error'>
      <p ng-message='required'>Birthdate is Required</p>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```